# javax.net.ssl logging timestamp format has strange hours value

Tags: python, logging, jetty

I'm using Python to parse some logfiles produced via jetty.net.ssl on an external platform running a JVM to which I have no access.

For reasons I don't understand (and nor can I find documented anywhere) the log timestamps have the first hour of each day expressed as `24` rather than `00` e.g.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|Mux|2022-07-01 24:00:11.298 UTC|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:334|WRITE: TLSv1.3 application_data, length = 31
```

which corresponds to 2022-07-**01** 00:00:11.298 rather than 2022-07-**02** 00:00:11.298

This format breaks things like Python's `datetime.datetime()` and `dateutils.parser.parse()`. I can code around this, stripping out the various elements of the timestamp string using a regex and altering the hour where necessary, along the lines of

```py
        timere = re.compile(r"^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s+(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{2})\.(\d{3}).*$")
        if not (match:=timere.match(tstr)):
            raise ValueError(f"Time string {tstr} is not valid")
        yy = int(match.groups()[0])
        mm = int(match.groups()[1])
        dd = int(match.groups()[2])
        hr = int(match.groups()[3]) % 24
        mi = int(match.groups()[4])
        se = int(match.groups()[5])
        us = int(match.groups()[6]) * 1000
        d = datetime.datetime(yy, mm, dd, hr, mi, se, us, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

I am, however, intrigued as to *why* the timestamps are in that format and is there some subtlety of which I am unaware? I'm kind of assuming that the developers used "24" as a valid hour deliberately for reasons I don't yet understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenJDK [`sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLLogger.java) uses the following syntax to output the timestamp.

```java
private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.SSS z";
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN, Locale.ENGLISH)
                     .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

This means the hour is represented by `kk` portion, which according to [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) is "clock-hour-of-day (1-24)"

Not sure if python has the same date/time pattern it can use.

Comment: No, Python's datetime type can only accept hours in the range [0..23].